# Wrapping a split string's substrings in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, split

How do i use javascript/jquery to select all `$('td.created')` and split the html on `<br>`, then wrap each section in span tags (so that i can add a class to span:first in order to style it).

The format of the string which is returned from `$('td.created').html()` is something like

`posted by User123 <br> Posted on 1/2/12 at 4:15PM`

Comment: Is it always going to be just two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible universal solution (works not only for 2 lines):

```
$("td.created").each(function() {
    var text = this.innerHTML.split("<br>");
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var span = $("<span />").html(text[i]);
        if (i == 0) span.addClass("first");
        span.appendTo("#element");
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7xQAL/

Comment: by the way i would like to modify the original TD and add the spans in there, not a new element. How might i do this?

Comment: @Tallboy Just empty the `td` contents and append to it: http://jsfiddle.net/7xQAL/1/.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td.created').each(function(i, html) {
    var newHtml = $(this).contents(),
        spans = [];
    newHtml.each(function() {
        var html = (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'br') ? '<br>' : '<span>' + this.textContent + '</span>';
        spans.push(html);
    });
    $(this).html(spans.join(''));
});
```

DEMO ( using DIV Container)
http://jsfiddle.net/PVLek/